# Device screen never turns off

Tags: android

I have an Activity that contains a `VideoView`, `OSMDroid MapView` and a custom `View` class. All other things are normal Android widgets.

```
mapView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
...
videoView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
...
view.setKeepScreenOn(false);
```

I call `setKeepScreenOn(false)` for these three views and I checked that there is no `keepScreenOn` in my XML layout file. But while I am in this Activity, screen never turns off. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Do you have any window flags set? Check if you have any WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON somewhere or if one of these views do that by default.

Comment: No. I have not set such flag in my Activity and my custom View. But I am not sure about VideoView and MapView.

Comment: And Activity definition in AndroidManifest: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`, `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`,`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: Just checking: You are not by any chance running this on your phone with debug on and set to keep screen on as well, right? And could you post your full code here?

Comment: I unchecked stay awake in USB debugging.

Comment: You can try removing these views individually or just have a naked activity in the extreme case to make sure your device sleeps at some point.